# Emacs 23.1.50.1 hangs ramdomly for 6-8 seconds on Windows XP

Tags: windows, emacs, installation

I have EmacsW32 23.1.50.1 emacs working on my windows XP machine. It hangs randomly for 5 to 8 seconds and quite frustrating.

Any one has solution?

I even tried using emacs win32 binaries (23.1) from gnu ftp site and that also hangs for few seconds.

Here some notable processmonitor logs

10:56:59.9888359 PM  **CreateFile** C:\usr\spool\mail\  **PATH NOT FOUND**  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a

10:57:55.5073038 PM **QueryAllInformationFile** C:\emacs.emacs.d\auto-save-list    **BUFFER OVERFLOW** CreationTime: 8/27/2009 12:51:26 PM, LastAccessTime: 1/5/2010 10:54:40 PM, LastWriteTime: 1/5/2010 10:08:15 PM, ChangeTime: 1/5/2010 10:08:15 PM, FileAttributes: D, AllocationSize: 0, EndOfFile: 0, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: True, IndexNumber: 0x1000000001f702, EaSize: 0, Access: Read Attributes, Synchronize, Position: 0, Mode: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word

Comment: Is Emacs hanging (unresponsive), or is the CPU busy doing something else?

Comment: I have an installation of GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) on my Windows XP machine.  I have no such problems.  I'll avoid moving up to your version !

Comment: do you have any customization going on yet in your .emacs or other init files?

Comment: @OtherMichael, seems like CPU is busy. I could type after 6 seconds. But hanging happens very often.
@Tim Hoolihan, I haven't done any modification in my .emac files

Comment: When does it hang? Did you try a C-g when it's hung to see if what it was doing was interruptible? Some more details are necessary before I can suggest an answer.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim, it hangs when I type the text simply .txt file extention. Sometimes while clicking on menu hangs. It hangs while saving the file on disk. Also I have Ido mode, when I try C-X C-F also hangs for quite some times

Comment: Emacs23 does the same thing on Ubuntu Linux Lucid Lynx. I am forced to use gedit now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem using EmacsW32 23.1.50 on WinXP. One change I made that had a significant improvement (for me anyway) was to add the following to my `.emacs` file:

```
; try to improve slow performance on windows.
(setq w32-get-true-file-attributes nil)
```

It seems this variable was changed to default to "true" relatively recently and is known to cause some slow-down problems around file access. I still get some random hangs now and then (probably due to my `.emacs` customisations) but it is much better now.

Comment: This improves a bit. But opening a file in emacs with C-X C-F took nearly 15 seconds and sometimes it struck for seconds when navigating files. I tried using ido mode and without ido mode. the same issue

Comment: thanks a million luapyad!!. You saved my time in figuring out the issue. File Open seems to very slow but I can live with that.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Please try stopping Netlogon service in "Services" control panel. That solved the problem in my case. See the excellent article http://www.hydrus.org.uk/journal/emacs-netlogon.html that saved me from the agony.

This only applies to a small (yet increasing?) group of users that:

- use corp issue laptop
- use windows 7
- use emacs for R editor
- suddenly see her emacs working very slow

Comment: This solution solved my problem. I change NegativeCachePeriod to 43200 follow the article.

Comment: This is exactly my use case and disabling the netlogon cleared up the problem for Emacs 24 as well.

Comment: Change NegativeCachePeriod using group-policy editor, instead of the registry directly:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758635%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks! This solved this issue for me. To find windows list of services via control panel, see this article here: http://www.wikihow.com/Start-Services-in-Windows

Answer (score 5):

I was having similar issues and traced it to network timeouts on Windows.  In my particular case, it was due to ido.el, which keeps a cached list of directory contents.  At startup, ido was trying to check the cached directories, which included network shares on both my home network and my work network – there were always some nonexistent hosts, no matter which network I was on.

Because my problem was originating with ido (sort of), the solution for me was to set ido-max-dir-file-cache to 0 (via customize-variable or init.el), then exit Emacs, delete ~/.emacs.d/.ido.last, and restart Emacs.  Based on what I saw in another thread, it's important to make sure all instances of Emacs are closed before trying to delete .ido.last.  There may be other ido variables that need to be changed, but so far, this solution is working for me.

Comment: By the way, Process Monitor was hugely helpful for figuring this out.

Answer (score 4):

Without some debugging output it will be difficult to say what is causing the delay.

Since delays are often caused by IO operation timeouts, I recommend running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what Emacs is doing while it is hanging.

Comment: Completely agree. The one culprit I've noticed is remote files, usually with a variety of things like auto-revert, auto-save...

Answer (score 3):

I have windows 7, that was happening to me because i was using Classic Windows UI, once i changed to the default theme it worked great, maybe also Themes service has something to do with that, so if you stopped it, try running it.

Comment: This just saved me hours of troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

After disabling global-auto-revert-mode, the system does far less I/O. For me, this seemed to have solved the problem.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer! I was getting periodic freezes, but on Linux. We have a super slow RAID, so it must've been hanging every time it went to check the files for reversion. Global auto revert is nice, but it was making emacs almost unusable for me, but I probably would not have figured it out without your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the disabling netlogon answer. It turned out that turning off netlogon was giving me issues with networked drives so it was a nuisance to disable it. I discovered that a long time I switched my dns provided to google's public dns. This turns out to be a very bad idea in a corporate domain. I switched it back to auto-detect dns and the problem went away.